# Sending Successfully Apple Push Notification through java servlet but cant display on ios device

Tags: java, ios, iphone

I am trying to implement Apple Push Notification from java. I have created development and production certificate,profile and its working fine and push was successfully sent but notification cant display on ios devices. If I send notification from PHP using PEM File, its working fine.

Below is the code for Java.

```
try {

        PushNotificationPayload payload = PushNotificationPayload.complex();


            payload.addAlert("Hello World!");


        List<PushedNotification> notifications1 = Push
                .payload(
                        payload,
                        "E:/J2EEWorkspace/SampleNotification/WebContent/CertificatesDev.p12",
                        "iphone", false, token);

        for (PushedNotification notification : notifications1) {

            if (notification.isSuccessful()) {

                System.out.println("Notification send successfully...");
            } else {
                String invalidToken = notification.getDevice().getToken();
                System.out.println("Notification errror..." + invalidToken);
            }
        }

    } catch (CommunicationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeystoreException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

If above code is execute then I am getting the "Notification send successfully..." log but cant display on ios devices.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not specific enough to detect the problem, but the issue might be the mode of app. Does it running in development mode or in production mode? If it is in development mode, you should send push to APNS with sandbox destination. In addition to this, I suggest using https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns.